# Select only limited colums in a csv file in python

Tags: pandas

I have a list of item numbers as follows.

```
item_numbers = [1,2,5]
```

I also have a csv file that contains the ingredients of the item_numbers.

```
,sugar, protein, salt, oil
0, 0.2, 0.3, 0,   0
1, 0,    0,  0.2, 0.8
2, 0.4,  0,  0,   0
```

Now, I want to get the ingredients for the items in my list where the value is greater than zero (if value == 0, I don't need that ingredient)

```
E.g., item 1 in 'item_numbers' list -> ['salt', 'oil']
```

Is it possible to do it using pandas?

Comment: So for each row, you want a list of column names where the value > 0? What do you want to do with the output? save it as a new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first select rows by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), remove possible added rows with `NaN` by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and compare with `0` by [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html). Last for list use `apply`:

```
df = df.loc[item_numbers].dropna(how='all').gt(0).apply(lambda x: x.index[x].tolist(), 1)
print (df)
1    [salt, oil]
2        [sugar]
dtype: object
```

If you want values joined with `,`:

```
df = df.loc[item_numbers].dropna(how='all').gt(0)
s = np.where(df, ['{}, '.format(x) for x in df.columns], '')
out = pd.Series([''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s], index=df.index)
print (out)
1    salt, oil
2        sugar
dtype: object
```

---

```
print (df.dtypes)
sugar      float64
protein    float64
salt       float64
oil        float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: I think the simpliest is use `out = pd.DataFrame({'col': [''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s]}, index=df.index)` and then `out.to_csv('myfile.csv', index=False)`

Comment: And if need first column also `out.to_csv('myfile.csv')`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I get the following error. Please let me know how to correct it. TypeError: Could not operate 0 with block values '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'

Comment: I think problem is your data are not `floats`, but `str`.

Comment: Oh ya, That is a good point. I will check that. I got the same error for both your solutions.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again. However, in my csv file the first column name is empty, which depicts the item_number. May be that is the reason why I get outputs like this [Unnamed: 0, oil, protein]. Please let me know, how to omit searching that column?

Comment: Before my solution use `df = df.iloc[:,1:]` for omit first column.